# setValue of a form field on twig template

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4

I try to set the user informations who is logged-in on a twig template but I can't find a way.
In particular, I try to make a comments section and I would like the user to write only the comment text.Doing so, I would like to setAuthor( app.user.username) on the template twig because I cannot get user information on the Controller file.

so on my controller file,in the function show, I put this :

```
 if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()  ){
        $comment->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime())
                ->setExercice($exercice)
                //would like to do it but cannot
                //->setAuthor(app.user.username);
```

So I search a way to maybe make something like

`{{form_row(commentForm.author,{'attr': {
            'value':  app.user.username,
            'class':hidden
        }})}}`

Is there a way to do it ?

the error I get is :

```
Variable "hidden" does not exist.
```

Comment: I still have the author field displayed on the form ...  I made this : {{form_row(commentForm.author,{
      'attr': {'class':'hidden'},
      'value': app.user.username })
     }}

Comment: Why can't you "get user information on the Controller" ? Inject `Security $security` and call `$security->getUser()`. Is there another reason?

Comment: thanks It works now ! I didn't know about it , I'm just learning symfony yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original error, `Variable "hidden" does not exist.`, happens because you've attempted to reference `hidden` as if it were a variable or constant, rather than a literal string. To use it as a literal string you need to quote it:

```
{{ form_row(commentForm.author, {attr: {
    value: app.user.username,
    class: 'hidden'
}}) }}
```

You do not need to quote the keys of the array (e.g. `value:` and `class:`) because non-scalar values cannot be used as keys.

However as @msg pointed out you should not rely on the form on the view to obtain the user details. This opens the form up to manipulation, meaning anyone would be able to impersonate other people in any comment posted. Definitely populate that field of the `comment` entity directly during the controller. -- If you do this prior to checking if the form is submitted that information will be available to the view also, e.g. exposing `$comment` to the view would mean `{{ comment.username }}` would also work.